# ListPlot with Stacked Layout: Filling Color and Line Color

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, color

I have a Listplot like this:

`` data1 = {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`,  0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.002049040366095212`, 0.006046761623219565`,  0.`, 0.0040569597143900364`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.003932461533659998`,  0.`, 0.0009383675012055415`, 0.0039147455415398`,  0.0016435354273192113`, 0.0038090146680477125`,  0.001513840830449827`, 0.003641498216409037`}; ``

`ListPlot[{data1 + 0.1, data1 + 0.3, data1 + 0.4},PlotLayout -> "Stacked", Filling -> Automatic, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Yellow, Green},FrameStyle -> Black]`

[image]

So far, I have not found a way to make the filling color exactly the same as the line color. How can I do that?? It appears to me that `FillingStyle`does not work...

Comment: `FillingStyle -> Opacity[1]`?

Comment: Oh that was easy! thx

Answer (score 7):

Add

```
%/. Opacity[a_] :> Opacity[1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the plot color needs to be matched to the filling color, the opacity can be gleaned from the `FullForm` output for the plot and matched in `PlotStyle`.

```
data1 = {0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 
   0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.002049040366095212`, 0.006046761623219565`, 
   0.`, 0.0040569597143900364`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.003932461533659998`, 
   0.`, 0.0009383675012055415`, 0.0039147455415398`, 
   0.0016435354273192113`, 0.0038090146680477125`, 
   0.001513840830449827`, 0.003641498216409037`};

ListPlot[{data1 + 0.1, data1 + 0.3, data1 + 0.4}
 , PlotLayout -> "Stacked", Filling -> Automatic
 , Joined -> True
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.2, Blue], Opacity[0.2, Yellow], 
   Opacity[0.2, Green]}
 , FrameStyle -> Black
 ]
```

[image]